# where enterprise library 4.1 logger, logs?

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library

I have done its configurations using configuration wizard but I couldn't understand where it is logging messages. I even see app.config file but couldn't find any logging source.

Please guide me where it does logs and how I can check that log.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add fileName="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\EAMS\trace.log"
        header="----------------------------------------" footer="----------------------------------------"
        formatter="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="FlatFile TraceListener" />
      <add source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="Application" machineName="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xD;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xD;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xD;&#xA;)}"
        type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Formatted EventLog TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=YAWARLAPTOP;Initial Catalog=EAMS;Integrated Security=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure one or more [Trace Listeners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff664768%28PandP.50%29.aspx). Also see [Configuration Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff664760%28PandP.50%29.aspx)

**Edit 1**
Thank you for an example of you config file. You are logging your messages into Application Event Log. Please open this [Event Log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) as you normally do and you'll be able to see your messages in there.

**Edit 2**
In your original question you asked where the messages are logged. This answer has been provided to you. When you write a question, it's better to specify upfront, what are you trying to achieve. To log into a flat file, after you configured a flat file listener you need to add reference to this listener to your sources. See how it's done with the Event Log trace listener in your example and follow the same pattern.

Comment: I added TraceListener (flat file) and did configurations but it is still not writing in file. Can u plz review my config file and suggest.

Comment: Thanks @zespri, But I want to log errors in plain text file. plz advice.

Comment: I have removed FormatedEventLogTraceListner form Enterprise library configurmations but still couldn't make Flat file working.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. 
Authentication has been added to the email tracelistener in v5.0.

If you must use v4.1, there's a version of the email tracelistener with authentication on [EntLibContrib](http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/).