# Why Enterprise Library 4.1 Email TraceListener is not working?

Tags: c#, email, logging, enterprise-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where enterprise library 4.1 logger, logs ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896576/where-enterprise-library-4-1-logger-logs)

I am trying to use Enterprise library 4.1's email TraceListener but it is not working. Enterprise Library configuration is not showing the option to configure the SMTP userID and password. Is this handled by the library? How I can configure user id and password?

Here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true"
    defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="true">
    <listeners>
      <add toAddress="mytoid@hotmail.com" fromAddress="myfromid@gmail.com"
        subjectLineStarter="Error intimation" subjectLineEnder="" smtpServer="127.0.0.1"
        smtpPort="25" formatter="" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Email TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;Category: {category}&#xD;&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xD;&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xD;&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xD;&#xA;Title:{title}&#xD;&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xD;&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xD;&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xD;&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xD;&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xD;&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xD;&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xD;&#xA;)}"
        type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General" />
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Email TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Email TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Email TraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```